# xgboost CV with custom folds python

Tags: python, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm working with the data, where every patient can have different number of training examples. When running Xgboost CV I want to make sure that data from same patient is restricted to be present in same fold only, thus I need to use folds, which may have different number of indices in it.

At the moment when passing list of numpy arrays containing indices using 'fold' parameter in xgb.cv function I get:

*dtrain = dall.slice(np.concatenate([idset[i] for i in range(nfold) if k != i]))
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated*

I have implemented same procedure in R with no problems by passing my custom folds as list where each element is a vector of test fold's indices.

Could you please advice what is the proper way to pass custom indices to Python XGBoost CV function. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is old but I am putting down an answer as it came up for me on google search, when I was having a similar problem.

I wanted to use TimeSeriesSplit with xgboost cv but couldn't do it directly as the folds parameter expects KFold or StratifiedKFold, however, you can give your own list of indices as a list of tuples as shown below

```
train1 =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
test1  =  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

train2 =  [9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13]
test2 =   [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

train3=  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
test3 =  [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

tsFolds = [(train1, test1), (train2, test2), (train3, test3)]

xgbCV = xgb.cv(
    params = parameters, 
    dtrain = trainDMat, 
    num_boost_round = num_boost_round,
    nfold = len(tsFolds),
    folds = tsFolds,
    metrics = {'rmse'},
    early_stopping_rounds = early_stopping_rounds,
    verbose_eval = True,
    seed = seed     
)
```